# Analyzing group form given generator relation

Tags: group-theory

Given $G$ be any finite group and $a,b\in G$ s.t $o(a)=7$ and $O(b)=49$ with the condition $aba^{-1}=b^8$ then consider the following statement :

a)$G$ must be an abelian group

b)If $a,b$ generate the group $G$ then order of $G$ is $7^3$

c)$7^3$ is the order of the proper subgroup of $G$

.-------------

Option a is not true by using contradiction but what about others option ???

Comment: Some helpful suggestions: (1) Spelling matters.  I think you meant "statements", rather than "statement" but what you wrote literally suggests we take (a), (b), and (c) together as a compound statement. (2) Don't use shorthand unless you know it is correct shorthand.  Numbers aren't groups, but $7^3$ can't be used as shorthand for any group of order $7^3$ because by convention it refers specifically to the elementary abelian group of that order (the direct product three cyclic groups of order $7$).  If that's not what you meant by it, then you asked a different question that you meant to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $G= \langle a,b| a^7,b^{49}, aba^{-1}b^{-8}\rangle$. 
The third relator says that any element in $G$ can be written in the form $a^kb^m$. So $|G|\leq 7^{3}$. Further more $|G|>49$ as the order of $b$ is $49$, and therefore 49 divides $|G|$. So you have $7^3$ possible choices for the elements in $G$.

Comment: The first relator should be $a^7$, not $a^8$. Your argument proves that $|G| \le 7^3$ rather than $|G|=7^3$, although the assumptions about orders of $a$ and $b$ in the question suggests that  we are allowed to assume that $|G|>49$, and hence $|G| = 7^3$.

Comment: Oh right Thank you! I edited it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually confused now, why can't the order of the group be $49*3$ for example? I know that The group could have at least $2$ left $\langle b \rangle$ cosets, namely $a<b>, <b>$. which gives $2*49$ elements. Why more?

Comment: We are told that $o(a)=7$ and $o(b)=49$. So $b \ne b^8$, and hence $a$ does not centralize $b$. In fact no nontirival power of $a$ can centralize $b$,  and so $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = 1$ and hence $|\langle a,b \rangle| \ge |\langle a \rangle||\langle b \rangle| = 7^3$.